# while loop is either crashing or not performing the desired actions - very confused

Tags: javascript, while-loop, minesweeper

I am building a Minesweeper game with vanilla JavaScript. I have a Grid class that handles logic on the grid, a Space class that acts basically as a container for space properties, and a Game class that handles game logic.

In the Grid class, I have a method called `openAdjoiningSpaces`. The intended behaviour of this method is to open all connected spaces on the board in each direction starting with the clicked empty space, and terminating when the next space borders a mine. If you aren't familiar with Minesweeper you can see this behaviour at http://minesweeperonline.com/.

The `openAdjoiningSpaces` method calls another method, `getBorderingSpaces`. This method accepts the clicked space as an argument and returns an array that contains each bordering space, including spaces that touch at the corners.

When `openAdjoiningSpaces` is called, it first gets the bordering spaces that don't contain a mine and puts them in an array called `toOpen`. The method then uses a while loop. In the while loop, each space in `toOpen` is opened, and then for each space that is opened, its bordering spaces are obtained and if they are empty, they are added to an array called `next`. At the end of the loop, if the `next` array has a length greater than 0, the `toOpen` variable is reassigned to `next`, otherwise the loop terminates.

This should cause the desired behaviour, but it isn't. Each time I rewrite it in another way, it either crashes the browser (even though it is not an infinite loop), or it only opens up the surrounding spaces of the clicked space and then terminates. Here is the method itself:

```js
    openAdjoiningSpaces(space)
    {
        if (space.isEmpty) {

            let loop = true;

            var toOpen = [ ...this.getBorderingSpaces(space).filter(space => !space.hasMine)];

            while (loop) {

                const next = [];

                toOpen.forEach(space => {

                    this.openSpace(space.id);

                    const neighbouring = this.getBorderingSpaces(space);

                    neighbouring.forEach(space => {
                        if (!space.hasMine && space.isEmpty) {
                            next.push(space);
                        }
                    });
                });

                if (next.length > 0) {
                    toOpen = next;
                    break;
                } else {
                    loop = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to create this space opening behavior for two days now. Each time I get close to succeeding, the grid still displays some kind of buggy behavior. All this afternoon I have continually tried to rewrite this method in different ways, to no avail. I'm at my wits end and really need some outside input. Please don't hesitate to ask me to clarify anything about the code. One thing I should clarify is that Space objects have two separate properties `hasMine` and `isEmpty`. The first just refers to whether the space has a mine or not. The second refers to whether it contains a number. Maybe a design flaw, I don't know but I thought I should mention that.

Comment: Just to clarify, the while loop should go on until `next.length === 0`? If that's the case, on your code you're always ending the loop either way (`break` breaks out the loop), so you should remove the `break`. In any case, could you include the code of `this.getBorderingSpaces`? Even better if you can also add a few test "spaces" and the expected result.

Comment: It helps to post valid code, there appears to be a missing keyword in the first line.

Comment: @RobG There is no missing keyword. Methods in JavaScript omit the `function` keyword.

Comment: The code **as posted** contains syntax errors.

Comment: I can't post the `getBorderingSpaces` method here because it's too long. However, it does correctly obtain all spaces that touch the target spaces.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander please add the extra code to the question, it's awkward to read it from a comment

Comment: @RobG Thanks for that really useful comment. Very appreciated.

Comment: @SrThompson I'm not sure what specifically would be useful to show you. Instead I am going to link the whole class from github for you: https://github.com/michaelacook/minesweeper/blob/master/src/classes/Grid.js

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit tricky to find, but there is a bug in `openAdjoiningSpaces`. When you add items to `next` you never check if the current space is already opened. This caused the `isOpen` array to get larger every iteration, making the loop never ending. Add this to your code and remove the `break` after `toOpen = next`

Change this

```
toOpen.forEach(space => {

                this.openSpace(space.id);

                const neighbouring = this.getBorderingSpaces(space);

                neighbouring.forEach(space => {
                    if (!space.hasMine && space.isEmpty) {
                        next.push(space);
                    }
                });
            });
```

For This

```
toOpen.forEach(space => {

                this.openSpace(space.id);

                const neighbouring = this.getBorderingSpaces(space);

                neighbouring.forEach(space => {
                    if (!space.hasMine && space.isEmpty && space.status !== 'open') {
                        next.push(space);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That did fix a bug, but the method still does not produce the desired outcome. Method still only opens the spaces that directly touch the clicked space, rather than fanning out.

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the `break` statement. Desired behaviour *almost* reached. The only problem now is that it only opens all empty spaces. I should actually keep opening spaces until it finds a space that borders a mine, then open that space and terminate. Getting closer though. I'm encouraged.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. If you're interested, here's the clone: https://michaelacook.github.io/minesweeper/
It's about 98% done.